# Vaadin Flow revert / undo value change without firing listener again

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

(Using Vaadin 18)

I have a value change listener on a combobox that opens a confirm dialog, allowing the user to confirm the change. Because this is within a value change listener, the value has technically already changed. Thus when they select "No" I need to revert the value. There doesn't appear to be any part of the API that can do this, aside from manually setting the value.

But when reverting via setValue(...) the listener fires a second time. I need to prevent it from firing again. Currently the only way I'm able to do it is with an extra "ignoreNextChange" boolean variable, which prevents the logic from running a second time. Is there an easier way to do this? I don't see anyway to add a listener that fires *before* the value change.

I can't simply ignore all non-client changes, because that breaks the binder. And altering the listener registration won't work from inside the listener because I would also need to add it back, which would cause it to fire anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You are right to assume, that you can not prevent the propagation of the
change inside an value change handler (it's happening after the fact).

Your main options are:

- You react only to "human made" change (from the client).  See
  [isFromClient inside the
  `ValueChangeEvent](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.6.2/com/vaadin/flow/component/HasValue.ValueChangeEvent.html#isFromClient--)
- Or de-couple the UI from the action (give the User some UI to request the
  change, ask again, then do the change) -- this could be done with a number of
  ways.  One way to do that could be writing your own field wrapping the combo
  box and only fire a change once the selection is confirmed.

Comment: Both of those methods work as well, but currently the solution requiring the least code for me was what I mentioned in the question - using a boolean to ignore the next change event.

Comment: Without knowing the exact things going in, this sounds like another
layer of state to keep track of or it will stab you in the back in the
future.  Ignoring "synthetic" changes in your change handler for the
user-dialog feels safer.  Just a gut feeling though.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using unbuffered Binder, with `binder.setBean()`? That has the underlying assumption that every write happens directly after the field value changes, not after a "confirm" step. If you want to delay the write (buffered binding), you should use `binder.writeBean(bean)` once you're ready. Note that this should be done without calling `setBean`.

Comment: It's not related to value in the bean changing, I'm trying to stop the actual value of the field from changing.

Comment: I think your wanted UI behaviour sounds more suited for buffered binding, is what I'm saying.